# Remove event from newly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove event to a newly created element, let's say I have no control to that dynamic element because it is generated from a plugin and there's no way for me to remove an event during plugin initialization.

So here's the case, I wanted to remove the event called `touchmove` in `jQuery("#dynamic_element")` element using `.off("touchmove")` on page load.

```
jQuery("#dynamic_element").off("touchmove")
```

Is there any jQuery method that I could use to poll if the dynamic element added in DOM is ready for manipulation?

I plan to mainly target iOS devices.

Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right approach? Is not adding it in the first place not an option?

Comment: yeah, that would be awesome if I can add the event in the first place. However I can't do it. I already updated the question above. Thanks for the comment

Comment: And I guess Mutation events/observers might be what you are looking for but those are far from being ready for library like jQuery which want to support old browser versions (especially IE and Safari). I believe not even jQuery 3 could implement it because there is no sensible way to shim it.

Comment: That's it! thanks! I guess it's okay since I planned to use it on iOS mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (IE11, FF, CH, SA iOS 7)

```
var mo = new MutationObserver(function(e){
   e.forEach(function(record) {
       var addedNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(record.addedNodes);           
       var dynamicElements = addedNodes.filter(function(e) { 
           return e.id && e.id === "dynamic_element";
       });

      if (dynamicElements.length) {
         jQuery(dynamicElements[0]).off("touchmove");
      }
   });
});

mo.observe(document.documentElement, { subtree: true,  childList: true });
```